# Putting Text Into A Div

Tags: html, css

I have this code that I am using to build a navigation bar and a heading on a site.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="nav">
    <div id="head">
        <li><a href="transitionyear.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TY Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Build a Bank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Enterprise Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gaisce</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Inclusion</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

```
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
  }
   #nav li {
  float: left; 
  }
   #nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
  }
   #nav li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff; 
  }
      #wrap {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  }
    #head {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 30px;
background-color: #fff;
border:  1px solid #ccc;
}
```

I cannot get the text into the top of the div (head div). I want to add "Marist College Transition Year" to above the navigation bar.

Comment: But then the div above the navigation bar goes.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` can be children of a `<ul>`.

Comment: What exactly are you tying to achieve ? "Marist College Transition Year" where ? do you want to add it to your lists of links ?

Comment: I want to put the text above the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

As a start, set up the HTML correctly, perhaps something like the following.

Your `li` need to be nested in the `ul` element.

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#wrap {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto; /* to prevent the float from interfering with the rest of the layout */
}
#head {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="head">
    <h2>Marist College Transition Year</h2>
  </div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="transitionyear.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TY Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Build a Bank</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enterprise Awards</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gaisce</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social Inclusion</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```